# Kafka Connect Consumer Group Lag Metrics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka Connect sink running. I'd like to monitor the lag for this.

I can manually get the lag by shelling into a broker and using the `kafka-consumer-groups` tool like so:

```sh
unset JMX_PORT; /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group connect-<my-kafka-connect-connector> --describe
```

that will give me something like:

```
GROUP                                 TOPIC                 PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                                                             HOST            CLIENT-ID
connect-<my-kafka-connect-connector>  <my-topic>            0          1414248272      2775658553      1361410281      connector-consumer-<my-kafka-connect-connector>-<uuid>                                  /<my-host-ip>   connector-consumer-<my-kafka-connect-connector>-0
```

that's the lag information that I want, but I want this in a Prometheus metric that I can put on a dashboard and monitor and set alerts on.

I'm ingesting the Kafka broker metrics and the Kafka Connect metrics, neither of which seem to have this information. I've poured through the Prometheus metric output with `curl` and `grep` and this information isn't there.

I'm runnning Kafka Connect via the official Confluent Helm chart (https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka-connect) with default Prometheus metrics export. This works, I can get basic metrics but no information on lag:

```sh
kubectl -n kafka exec -it kafka-connect-cp-kafka-connect-<id> -c cp-kafka-connect-server /bin/bash

# This will show exactly one metric with simple "running" status.
curl localhost:5556/metrics | grep <my-topic-name-or-connector-name>

cp_kafka_connect_connect_connector_metrics{connector="<my-connector-name>",status="running",task="0",} 1.0
```

I see third party add-ons like the following:
https://github.com/lightbend/kafka-lag-exporter

This seems to do exactly what I want, but I'd rather not add another third party component to my production setup unless absolutely necessary. Do I really need a third party utility to get something so basic? If a third-party tool is necessary, are there are similar third party utilities that I should evaluate or consider?